# Catch cancellation request from a custom AzureDevOps task

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

Azure DevOps pipelines. Can a custom task somehow detect that the user has cancelled the build/release job **mid-execution** and quit gracefully? I'm wondering about both the Node API and the Powershell API.

To clarify, I'm talking about *this* kind of cancel:

[image]

Not about conditional execution of tasks.

Nothing to that effect at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/azure-pipelines-task-lib.md

"Impossible" is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a custom task somehow detect that the user has cancelled the build/release and quit gracefully?

In DevOps pipeline, `Cancel` is not detected inside the task, but in the `condition` expression.

For example, the last task will run only when it's canceled before.
[image]

You can set the `condition` on `stage`, `job` and `step` level. Please check the official docs below for the details:

[Pipeline behavior when build is canceled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#pipeline-behavior-when-build-is-canceled)

[Job status check functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions)

With the condition, make sure the task will run even it's canceled by user, then you can consider what to check inside the task.

For example, to get the job, task status in current build(rest api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1))

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo step1
          sleep 30   #  can cancel for testing.
        displayName: step1

      - script: echo step2
        displayName: step2

      - script: echo step3
        condition: canceled()
        displayName: execute only when canceled before

  - job: job2
    condition: always()
    dependsOn: job1
    steps:
      - script: echo step 1
        displayName: step1 in job2
      - powershell: |
          # Define the URL for the REST API call
          $url = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(build.buildid)/timeline?api-version=6.0"

          # Make the REST API call
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get

          # Loop through the records and print the status of each stage, job, and step
          foreach ($record in $response.records) {
              Write-Host ("Name: " + $record.name)
              Write-Host ("Type: " + $record.type)
              Write-Host ("Status: " + $record.result)
              Write-Host ("--------------------------------")
          }
        env:
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
```

[image]

Edit, update based on the new screenshot:

As per the screenshot, you are canceling for classic release pipeline.

The situation could be complicated:

1. If you start the release pipeline, and `immediately` cancel it, **cannot detect the cancel** in task.

If you check the run log, it shows `no stage deployed` as below:

[image]

2. If you cancel the release run after at least 1 task started(like the screenshot you shared), as stated before, you can detect the cancel in the new task. The referred rest api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

In the powershell task:

[image]

With custom condition in the task behind:
[image]

[image]

Can detect the canceling in rest api response -> deploysteps -> operationstatus.

[image]

Comment: Great answer to a different question. :) Edited, see if that makes sense. The blame is on the AzDevOps team for using the word "cancel" for two different things.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, thanks for the clarification!  I have updated the reply as per your screenshot, please check.

Comment: All the talk about conditional task execution is still utterly irrelevant to the purpose  of this question - feel free to leave those in, but it's a waste of screen (at least for me). That said, I hear you about polling for release status (still got check if the environment contains sufficient information for that), but one would think the task executor knows about cancellation and would be able to communicate that to tasks somehow, without reaching out all the way back to the REST server.

Comment: It appears you are looking for some kind internal method which can defined in the custom task. If user cancel during the task is running, detect the cancel and quite gracefully. If my understanding is correct, there is no such method. If there is any misunderstanding, please update the query description with more details, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was interested in. I thought the words "mid-execution" in the question were clear enough. "Impossible" is a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks @SevaAlekseyev! The stage could have many jobs, and each job could have many tasks, so what i understood before for `mid-execution` is to cancel the stage/job but not focused on task which is canceling. Yes, there's no such method.